# PHP - SQLite Issue: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php, html, database, sqlite, authentication

I've spent far too much time trying to solve this issue. None of the fixes I've found have worked thus far. I would really appreciate any help.

The issue occurs when I attempt to redirect to a new page after checking login information. This is my code that runs after the login button is pressed:

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  session_start();
  $database = new SQLite3('newdb.db');
  $fname=$_POST['fname'];
  $lname=$_POST['lname'];

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM guests WHERE fname = '$fname' and lname = '$lname'";
  $result= $database->query($sql);
  $row = $result->fetchArray();
  if (!empty($row)){
      header ("Location: home.php");
      die();
  }
  else {echo "NOPE";}
  $database->close();
?>
<?php ob_flush(); ?>
```

As you can see, I have tried adding in ob_start/flush which hasn't helped. I've also checked for extra white space and have tried multiple ways of writing the header code. Nothing has worked.

I assume I am overlooking something.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> It's also probably worth mentioning that the error message says it's coming from my check.php page on line 1. Although nothing seems to be there.

Comment: is there a space or something before the first `<?php` ?

Comment: there doesn't seem to be anything, yet the error message tells me the problem is in the first line. I've opened up the file in a few editors...nothing.

Comment: To allow you to debug this later, have you considered using 'output buffering'? [outcontrol.configuration.php)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php)

Comment: This may well be a byte-order mark: check which encoding you're using; if it's "UTF8 with BOM" or similar, change it to "UTF8".

Comment: the file is encoded as utf8, so I don't think it's due to BOM.
Regarding output buffering, I thought that's what I did with   ob_start(); at the top of my code.

Comment: It's worth noting that you have a horrible SQL injection hole in this code that urgently needs fixing.

Comment: I'm aware, but I'd like to solve this issue before moving on to that.

Comment: I just noticed that enabling php.ini quickconfig and turning on output buffering has caused an internal server error...could this be the cause of my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Take the source view of your page, look at the top and make sure 
    that there is no blank lines exist. If a blank line is coming then
    remove this and try again.

Comment: How would I be able to edit this code? It's also probably worth mentioning that the error message says it's coming from my check.php page on line 1. Although nothing seems to be there.